# Display non-geographical maps using R leaflet + shiny

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm trying to develop a digitizing software for morphometrics data acquisition. What I(m trying to build is basically a viewer interface for images, along with creating/editing/deleting simple features like points, polylines and polygons. I think building this on top of `mapview`and `mapedit` packages, so using `leaflet` behind the curtain.

One blocking aspect for this now is to properly display images using pixels coordinates. So far, I manage to display any image using `raster` with `xmx`= 1 (and the ratio for `ymx`) but that's far from being clean (ie we need to retransform into pixels, scales are wrong, etc.).

I would pretty much need what's described in the [leafletjs doc](http://leafletjs.com/examples/crs-simple/crs-simple.html) for non-geographical maps. On the `leaflet()` side, `L.CRS.Simple` seems to be the way to go, but, for such raster, we still need a projection. There seems to be no `proj4` for pixels coordinates, `leaflet`seems to be able to use them, but `R leaflet` still wants a projection CRS for the raster.

How can we circumvent this problem and project an image (as a raster) in pixels coordinates and on a cartesian plane? A reproducible and minimal example follows (you can unzoom and see that the raster is projected in the Atlantic Ocean...).

Thanks a bunch for any help.

```
    # dependencies
    library(jpeg)
    library(raster)
    library(leaflet)
    library(leaflet.extras)
    library(mapview)
    library(mapedit)

    # dl an image
    path <- "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/58/CheHigh.jpg/280px-CheHigh.jpg"
    che <- tempfile()
    download.file(path, che, mode="wb")
    im <- readJPEG(che)

    # prepare a raster from it
    r  <- raster(xmn=0, xmx=1,
                 ymn=0, ymx=nrow(im)/ncol(im),
                 ncols=ncol(im), nrows=nrow(im))
    r <- setValues(r, as.numeric(t(im)))

    # prepare the leaflet
    lf <- leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% addRasterImage(r)
    # view it
    editMap(lf) # after editing, returns an object I think I can manage
```

Comment: for information, tim- proposed something around `mapview::plainview` ([here](https://github.com/r-spatial/mapedit/issues/67)); we'd still need editing capacities though.